# Integrating CA plex with jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

we are using CA plex Rapid aaplication development tool to develop the code. 
Is there any way where we can integrate it with jenkins ?

we are now working on Continuous integfration and would like to see if anyone have any thoughts on that?
i see that there is plex API, can we leaverage that API build some wrapper around that ?

if there is already jenkin plugin available , please suggest

regards

Answer (score 0):

If anyone in the world can answer your question let alone CA or one of their partners such as CM First it would be on this forum [communities.ca.com/community/ca-plex-ca-2e](https://communities.ca.com/community/ca-plex-ca-2e)

BUT I very much doubt there are many sites using Jenkins and Plex. The model aPI you talk of is not mature enough to do what you want as I have pushed it to the very limits [www.stellatools.com](http://www.stellatools.com) and the idea of Continuous Integration has been constantly asked for but so far little progress.